# Trying to Group XML data and out to .csv - XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am having issues understanding grouping, even though I have read about the Muenchian grouping. I have xslt and xml code in which I need the output to be in .csv format. I am pulling data from a system via a report. The system allows employees to have different employee id numbers but only have one SSN. So the report can have multiple rows. I believe the right approach would be to group the employee by SSN then sort by hire date. This will allow me to determine the primary job (latest hire date). I want to include certain details from the child node such as EmpID, SSN, HireDate ect...Below is the .xsl and XML.

I am have problems with outputting the jobNo and RecordNo.

```
XLST:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="2.0"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Vantage_Deductions" 
xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:local="urn:this-stylesheet"
xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv" 
xmlns:this="this.file/eib" 
xmlns:lu='http://example.com/lookup'
exclude-result-prefixes="wd xtt etv xs this lu local"> 

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="NEWLINE" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>
<xsl:variable name="DELIMITER" select="','"/>
<xsl:variable name="QUOTE">"</xsl:variable>

<!--Function: FormatPhone - Remove non-number characters and add in dashes.
    Will also remove the +1 country code if it is present.-->
<xsl:function name="local:FormatPhone">
    <xsl:param name="phone"/>
       
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="header"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="body"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="header">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,'SSN',$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>  
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,'EmployeeID',$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>  
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,'HireDate',$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,'JobNo',$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,'RecordNo',$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="body">  
<xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_entry/wd:Benefit_Changes_by_Plan_group">
    <xsl:sort select="wd:EmployeeID"/> 
            
        <!--preventing Report_Entry values duplicates and pass to body-content template as parameters to get the right position -->            
        <xsl:if test="not(precding::wd:Report_Entry/wd:Benefit_changes_by_Plan_group[wd:EmployeeID/text() = current()/wd:EmployeeID/text()])">                                                   
            <xsl:call-template name="body-content">                                          
                <xsl:with-param name="param.EmployeeID" select="./wd:EmployeeID"/>       <!--leave this for now-->                             
            </xsl:call-template>   
             
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="body-content"> 
    
    <xsl:param name="param.EmployeeID"/>    

    <!--Extract the Expected Data-->            
    <xsl:for-each select"/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Benefit_Changes_by_Plan_group[wd:EmployeeID = $param.EmployeeID]">      
        <xsl:sort select="wd:HireDate
        " order="descending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,wd:SSN,$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>    
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,wd:EmployeeID,$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>                 
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,wd:HireDate,$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,wd:JobNumber,$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,position(),$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>

            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()= 1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,'Y',$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat($QUOTE,'N',$QUOTE,$DELIMITER)"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

****XML****
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.TEST.report/Vantage_Deductions">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Benefit_Changes_by_Plan_group>
            <wd:Worker wd:Descriptor="Humpty Dump">
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Ded>DED</wd:Ded>
            <wd:CF_SSN>000000987</wd:CF_SSN>
            <wd:HireDate>01/01/2020</HireDate>
            <wd:EmployeeID>002934</wd:EmployeeID>
            <wd:JobNumber>1</wd:JobNumber>
            <wd:Change_File>0</wd:Change_File>
        </wd:Benefit_Changes_by_Plan_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Benefit_Changes_by_Plan_group>
            <wd:Worker wd:Descriptor="Humpty Dump">
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Ded>JCP</wd:Ded>
            <wd:CF_SSN>000000987</wd:CF_SSN>
            <wd:HireDate>03/01/2015</HireDate>
            <wd:EmployeeID>002934</wd:EmployeeID>
            <wd:JobNumber>1</wd:JobNumber>
            <wd:Change_File>0</wd:Change_File>
        </wd:Benefit_Changes_by_Plan_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Benefit_Changes_by_Plan_group>
            <wd:Worker wd:Descriptor="Zippy Doo">
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Ded>81</wd:Ded>
            <wd:CF_SSN>000000377</wd:CF_SSN>
            <wd:HireDate>02/01/2018</HireDate>
            <wd:EmployeeID>005927</wd:EmployeeID>
            <wd:JobNumber>1</wd:JobNumber>
            <wd:Change_File>0</wd:Change_File>
        </wd:Benefit_Changes_by_Plan_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>


Intended output in Excel

SSN        EmpID    HireDate    JobNo    RecordNo  
000000987  002934   01/01/2020  0        1  
000000987  002934   03/01/2015  1        2  
000000377  005927   02/01/2018  0        1
```

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. I will try to update this. I see if there is a youtube video that explains how to enter code in stack overflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output as .csv code, not as picture and your current XSLT attempt.

Comment: P.S.I don't see any need for grouping here. AFAICT, all you want to do is sort by SSN and then by hire date.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I made the updates per your post. Any other recommendations?